# List with different type on one line in Elixir

Tags: list, elixir

How to print a list on one line in Elixir. Thank you :)

```rb
a = ["Hey", 100, 452, :true, "People"]
defmodule ListPrint do
   def print([]) do
   end
   def print([head | tail]) do 
      IO.puts(head)
      print(tail)
   end
end
ListPrint.print(a)

#⇒ Hey
#  100
#  452 
#  :true 
#  People
```

I need:

```rb
#⇒ Hey 100 452 :true People
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward solution would be to use [`Enum.join/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#join/2):

```rb
["Hey", 100, 452, :true, "People"]
|> Enum.join(" ")
|> IO.puts()
#⇒ Hey 100 452 true People
```

---

If you want to use recursion and print elements one by one, you might use [`IO.write/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html?#write/2) instead of `IO.puts/2`:

```rb
defmodule ListPrint do
 def print([]), do: IO.puts("")
 def print([head | tail]) do 
   IO.write(head)
   IO.write(" ")
   print(tail)
 end
end
ListPrint.print(["Hey", 100, 452, :true, "People"])
#⇒ Hey 100 452 true People
```

*Sidenote:* both `IO.puts/2` and `IO.write/2` implicitly call [`Kernel.to_string/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#to_string/1) (which in turn calls the implementation of `String.Chars` protocol on the argument,) resulting in atoms printed without leading colon. Even your code would print `true`, not `:true`. To preserve colon, one should use [`IO.inspect/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html?#inspect/3) instead, which is omnivorous.

```rb
IO.inspect(["Hey", 100, 452, :ok, "People"])  
#⇒ ["Hey", 100, 452, :ok, "People"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`IO.puts/2` adds a newline to any string passed.
If you do not want the newline, use `IO.write/2`
such as:

```rb
a = ["Hey", 100, 452, :true, "People"]
defmodule ListPrint do
   def print([]) do
   end
   def print([head | tail]) do 
      IO.write(to_string(head) <> " ")
      print(tail)
   end
end
ListPrint.print(a)
```